# Decompose $Sym^2 (V)$ into direct sum of irreducible $S_n$-subrepresentations, where $V$ is the $2$-dimensional representation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

> Decompose $\operatorname{Sym}^2 (V)$ into direct sum of irreducible sub representations. (Hint: Again consider the action on basis vectors.)"

Here, $V=\Bbb C^2$, with its standard basis, and the action $\pi$ we are considering is characterized by
$$
\pi(12) = \pmatrix{0&1\\1&0} ,
\qquad
\pi(123) = \pmatrix{\omega&0\\0&\omega^2} .$$

The hint says,

> Consider the action on basic vectors.

(See the original problem statement [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2YIW.jpg).)

---

So I think the basis vectors of $\operatorname{Sym}^2(V)$ are
$e_1 \oplus e_1 , e_2 \oplus e_2$ 
$e_1 \oplus e_2 + e_2 \oplus e_1 $

To decompose it into irreducible representation I need to find it to be isomorphic to two vector spaces (?), I think.

Would really appreciate some advice, as I haven't quite 'clicked' with representation theory

Comment: You should typeset the original question here---it will make the question more readable and make the question more likely to receive an answer besides.

Comment: ok thanks @Travis here it is: ********"Decompose $Sym^2(V)$ into a direct sum of irreducible subreps. (Hint: again consider the action on basis vectors.)" ********

Comment: One really ought to make this post self-contained, which in particular means defining the representation $V$. At least this should contain the information in the problem statement, both the material before subquestion (i), as well as subquestion (iii).

Comment: ok ive edited it

Comment: You have the basis of vectors of ${\rm Sym}^2(V)$ correct, so what you should do next is to work out the $3 \times 3$ matrices for the actions of $(12)$ and $(123)$ on ${\rm Sym}^2(V)$ using these basis vectors. I think if you do that, then the decomposition of ${\rm Sym}^2(V)$ into irreducibles should be obvious.

Comment: @thinker I've taken the liberty of formatting the question statement for readability.

Comment: @DerekHolt I can't seem to do it... Do I need to multiply the matricies above with the basis elements?

Comment: You can work them all out using $\pi(1,2)(e_1)=e_2$, $\pi(1,2)(e_2)=e_1$, $\pi(1,2,3)(e_1) = \omega e_1$, $\pi(1,2,3)(e_2) = \omega^2 e_2$. For example, $\pi(1,2,3)(e_1 \oplus e_1) = \omega e_1 \oplus \omega e_1 = \omega^2 (e_1 \oplus e_1)$ (the $\oplus$ is bilinear).